# Get object within a list by objects attribute

Tags: json, r, list, object

in short i have this json structure

```
{
 "inputSettings": [
    { "id":      1,"name": "111" },
    { "id":      2,"name": "222" },
    { "id":      3,"name": "333" } 
    ...
 ] 
}
```

The list entries are all objects from a specific class (e.g. result which is represented by an id and a name). I read this json with RJSONIO.

Now i need a function which gives me the "name" for any id. So prefered usage would be:

```
setting = settings2id(2) #=222
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Right now, it sounds like you're asking us to write your code for you.  That is not what SO is for.  Instead, try a few things and share them here.  Then ask your question explaining why your approaches didn't work.

Comment: It seems pretty basic: read the json using fromJSON(text) and get a list structured like the json; turn that list into something simpler to subset (e.g. matrix or data.frame) then use it. Have you already followed these steps ? If so, which step gives you troubles ?

Comment: okay here it is...
`a=do.call(rbind.data.frame, biglistFROMJson$inputSettings)`
`a$name[which(a$id==3)]` This gives me 333 and `Levels: 111 222 333` how can i disable the levels output?

Comment: okay this will work either `subset(a, a$id==2)$name` but still getting the levels ouput...

Comment: so now I know why the levels output is shown. Thats why R treats characters as factors. I also read that this behaviour can disabled with as.is = ..., but I only read about it in context of filereading

Comment: Yeah, the automatic conversion of strings into factors is sometimes annoying... unfortunately you can't disable this behaviour on `rbind` (it works on `cbind`, `data.frame`, `read.table` etc by setting the parameter stringsAsFactors=F) but you can change the global option `options(stringsAsFactors=F)`.

Comment: Note that changing the global option means that for the whole life of the R session the default value of stringsAsFactors will be false...

Comment: @digEmAll Thanks for that! I Will try it. Is there any other way of getting my result especially concerning performance aspects?

Comment: @user3199454: if the data.frame is really big, using data.table package may be worth a try. For an example have a look at my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the maximum speed in accessing the name by id, you can use data.table package e.g. :
(it also solves the "factors issue" without changing the global options)

```
library(RJSONIO)
library(data.table)

txt <- 
  '{
  "inputSettings": [
    { "id":      1,"name": "111" },
    { "id":      2,"name": "222" },
    { "id":      3,"name": "333" }
   ] 
}'

a <- fromJSON(txt)

# turn the list into a data.table
DT <- rbindlist(a$inputSettings)

# set id as data.table key to get maximum look-up speed
setkeyv(DT,cols='id') 

# get the name corresponding to 2
# N.B. the lookup is performed using binary search for maximum speed
name <- DT[J(2)]$name 

# > [1] "222"
```